# Does EntityFramework have the ability to check and not overwrite other people changes?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008

What I mean is as follows:

**Machine A** editing customer A, **Machine B** also opened customer A information for editing.

After **Machine A** updated customer A's information, **Machine B** clicked Save and overwrote the changes with the old information.

Can Entity Framework do some checking and throw an exception before Save? I think I read something about non-optimistic concurrency somewhere...

Comment: Try reading the documentation on concurrency

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just finish reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399228(v=vs.90).aspx , but the concurrency checking is applied by property? So if I have to make sure the whole entity is concurrency enable, I have to set all properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nvm, I might need to add a TimeStamp fields and check that instead.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at timestamp/row version fields.